# Change color pixel with PIL in Python but error message appear : "image index out of range"

Tags: python, colors, python-imaging-library, pixel

I would like to change color pixel of my image with this, but a message "out of range" appear and I don't know how resolve this...

```
from PIL import Image

picture_1 = Image.open("test.jpg")

largeur, longueur = picture_1.size

print(largeur,"*",longueur)

picture_2 = Image.new("RGB", (largeur, longueur))

for y in range(largeur) :
    for x in range(longueur) :
        picture_1.getpixel((x,y))
        r = 154 ; v = 152 ; b = 100
        picture_2.putpixel((x,y), (r, v, b))

picture_2.save("test2.jpg")
picture_2.show
```

Thanks for your help ^^

Comment: You have your indices backwards. Change `for y in range(largeur):` to `for x in range(largeur):` and `for x in range(longueur):` to `for y in range(longueur):`. Also, please learn [how to debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Oh, okay ^^ Thanks !